# refresh UIViewController when user returns to my app after being in another app

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to get a View Controller to execute a function when the my app regains focus.

I tried:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated);
        myFunc()
    }
```

This fires myFunc() if the user goes to another view in my app and then returns to this view.

However if the user does the following it won't refresh the view
1.  Double tap home button
2.  Select another open app
3.  Double tap home button
4.  Select my app

The view does not run myFunc in this instance.

What should I use to run myFunc if the user switches to another app and then back to mine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have your view controller register for UIApplicationWillEnterForeground notifications and call your method when you receive one.

See the application delegate docs for details of the app states you can listen for.